# FOR /F does not work for files that has spaces in their filenames

Tags: for-loop, cmd, permissions, icacls

I used this command:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b /s "C:\x\x\x\x\*Cyber-Unit*"') do icacls %i /grant "MetricUsers":(OI)(CI)F
```

But the files (cyber-unit) has their permissions changed only if their parent folder doesn't have space in his foldername.

Comment: `for /F` does work, you are using it wrongly; read the help when typing `for /?` into command prompt and read it very carefully; you will notice a `delims=` option, which defaults to _space_ and _tab_...

Comment: and besides `"delims="` (or `"tokens=*"`) don't forget to use `icalcs "%i" ...`

Answer (score 1):

Stephen and aschipfl have given you what you need.

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /s "C:\x\x\x\x\*Cyber-Unit*"') do icacls "%~i" /grant "MetricUsers":(OI)(CI)F
```

If this goes into a .bat script file, double variable percent signs.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s "C:\x\x\x\x\*Cyber-Unit*"') do (
    icacls "%%~i" /grant "MetricUsers":(OI)(CI)F
)
```

Comment: thank you for replying :) i tried it but it still didn't work  i replaced %i with "%~i" and added "tokens=*" but it gave me the same results. I also tried delims and got the same result.

Comment: @vegetables - Please copy and paste your current code into the question so people can see exactly what you are trying. Thanks.

Comment: thats the code that i used : for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /s "C:\x\x\x\x\*Cyber-Unit*"') do icacls "%~i" /grant "MetricUsers":(OI)(CI)F